# Monte Carlo Simulation in R for Simple Game with Assigned Distribution

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, montecarlo

I am trying to figure out how to create a Monte Carlo Simulation for a game in R.

In the game you have two players, P1 and P2. During each round, one player gets to take an action.
P1 takes the action 60% of the time.
P2 takes the action 40% of the time.

There are 3 actions in the game: A, B, and C.
A awards 3 points. P1 performs A with 20% likelihood, P2 performs A with 40% likelihood.
B awards 1 point. P1 performs B with 30% likelihood, P2 performs B with 50% likelihood.
C awards 1 point. P1 performs C with 50% likelihood, P2 performs C with 10% likelihood.

The game is over once one player has reached 10 points.

I want to see at the end of 1000 games:

1. The count of wins for P1 and P2
2. The count of actions A, B, and C across all games

I have been able to write code that figures out the number of wins and the count of actions taken if:

1. P1 and P2 take actions with equal likelihood (ie, 50%)
2. Each action rewards the same amount of points
3. Each action is taken with the same likelihood(ie, 33% for any action for either player)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```r
draw <- function(players, actions, points, probs) {
  player <- sample(players$player, 1, prob = players$prob)
  s <- sample(actions, 1, prob = probs[[player]])
  list(player = player, action = s, points = points[[s]])
}
game <- function(players, actions, points, probs) {
  p <- c(P1 = 0L, P2 = 0L)
  total_actions <- c(A = 0L, B = 0L, C = 0L)
  while(all(p < 10L)) {
    d <- draw(players, actions, points, probs)
    p[d$player] <- p[d$player] + d$points
    total_actions[d$action] <- total_actions[d$action] + 1L
  }
  list(win = p >= 10L, actions = total_actions)
}
sim <- function(n, players, actions, points, probs) {
  r <- replicate(n, game(players, actions, points, probs), simplify = FALSE)
  wins <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(r, `[[`, "win"))
  tot_actions <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(r, `[[`, "actions"))
  names(wins) <- players$player
  names(tot_actions) <- actions
  cbind(wins, tot_actions)
}  

Players <- list(player = c("P1", "P2"), prob = c(0.6, 0.4))
Actions <- c("A", "B", "C")
Points <- c(A = 3, B = 1, C = 1)
Probs <- list(P1 = c(20, 30, 50)/100, P2 = c(40, 50, 10)/100)

# test run of one draw
draw(Players, Actions, Points, Probs)
#> $player
#> [1] "P2"
#> 
#> $action
#> [1] "B"
#> 
#> $points
#> [1] 1

# test run of one game
game(Players, Actions, Points, Probs)
#> $win
#>    P1    P2 
#>  TRUE FALSE 
#> 
#> $actions
#> A B C 
#> 2 6 6

# simulate 1000 games
set.seed(2023)
n <- 1000L
s <- sim(n, Players, Actions, Points, Probs)
# totals
colSums(s)
#>   P1   P2    A    B    C 
#>  594  406 2816 3854 3525
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Note

The games with parameters defined at the end of the question can be played with

1. `Players <- list(player = c("P1", "P2"), prob = c(0.5, 0.5))`
2. `Points <- c(A = 1, B = 1, C = 1)`
3. `Probs <- list(P1 = rep(1, 3)/3, P2 = rep(1, 3)/3)`